# Find largest folders in the repository and commit times of each developer

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm new to git and I need to analyze a git repository thus is there any way to find the top largest directories in a git repository (newest version) and can we find the commit times of each developer by time range and short them from high to low?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at some statistical tools for `git`. To list a few:

- [GitStats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/), written in Python and requiring Gnuplot for graphs
- [GitStat](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitstat/) (not the same as the previous one, it has no 's'!)
- [pepper](http://scm-pepper.sourceforge.net/) - a repository statistics and report tool
- [Gitdm](http://repo.or.cz/w/git-dm.git) (the "git data miner")
- [gitinspector](http://code.google.com/p/gitinspector/)